# C# to php to mysql

Tags: c#, mysql

I am running a server with a mysql database on it.
I am now making a C# program which has to put some data into the database.
For security reasons I would send the data to a php script which inserts the data in the local mysql database.

I am trying the code below, but when I use fiddler to check if the url is called, it doesn't show up, so it seems as if the url is never called.

My code looks like this:

```
    string result = string.Empty;
    string data2 = string.Empty;
    string[] postdata = new string[8];
            postdata[0] = "Date";
            postdata[1] = log.EndTime.ToString();
            postdata[2] = "Name";
            postdata[3] = log.OwnerTask.Schedule.Name;
            postdata[4] = "Status";
            postdata[5] = log.ParsedStatus;
            postdata[6] = "Message";
            postdata[7] = log.ParsedMessage;
            string Url = "http://x.x.x.x/send.php";
            System.Text.ASCIIEncoding ascii = new ASCIIEncoding();

            for (int i = 0; i < postdata.Length; i += 2)
            {
                data2 += string.Format("&{0}={1}", postdata[i], postdata[i + 1]);
            }

            data2 = data2.Remove(0, 1);

            byte[] bytesarr = ascii.GetBytes(data2);

            try
            {
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);
                request.Method = "POST";
                request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                request.ContentLength = bytesarr.Length;

                System.IO.Stream streamwriter = request.GetRequestStream();
                streamwriter.Write(bytesarr, 0, bytesarr.Length);
                streamwriter.Close();
                }
```

Can somebody help me out? Point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: `For security reasons I would send the data to a php script which inserts the data in the local mysql database.` - Seems like the worst possible approach from a security standpoint. PHP stuff can be viewed by anyone with a browser just by pressing "view source". Create a proper Web Service instead.

Comment: If you really want to go this route, I'd use the WebClient class which is a higher level wrapper for the HttpWebRequest.  It has a nice .UploadString() method if I remember correctly, which does POST requests.

Answer (score 1):

*More focused answer, based on the spot-on comment provided*

After writing to the stream, you should invoke `GetResponseStream` to actually perform the request:

```
    System.IO.Stream streamwriter = request.GetRequestStream();                
    streamwriter.Write(bytesarr, 0, bytesarr.Length);
    streamwriter.Close();
    var response = request.GetResponseStream(); // this will execute the request
    // [go on ...]
}
```

---

*Old answer, spotted the issue but missed the purpose of OP code, left for reference*

I'm not able at the moment to verify it in VS but this

```
System.IO.Stream streamwriter = request.GetRequestStream();
                                           ^^^^^^^
```

should be

```
System.IO.Stream streamwriter = request.GetResponseStream();
                                           ^^^^^^^^
```

as in: you want to parse the response, not the request (which your code never executes, that's why you don't see the URL being hit).

Comment: He needs both. First write the bytes to the request stream, then get the response from the response stream.

Comment: You're right, I missed that. I expanded the answer to be more focused on the specific need.